# How to say "Play along"?

Tags: grammar, words

I wanted to say something like:

> He was trying to deceive me, but to see how far he would go with that, I played along.

My attempt:

> 彼は僕を騙そうとしていたけど、どこまでやるつもりかわかるために、騙されていたようなふりをし続いた。

I have two main questions about it.

**1 - How do I express "To go far with words/actions"?**

**2 - How do I express "To play along with a situation"?**

Comment: I think you should post them as separate questions. The heading for this question is already pretty clear.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the context, you could also use the word 乗る something like...

> 一応{いちおう}（彼のごまかしに）**乗{の}っ**てやった

or

> （彼のごまかしに） **乗っ**たふりをして

Weblio also lists some translated example sentences with the phrase「調子を合わせる」

https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/play+along